# С# Использование аргумента main в другом классе

Tags: c#

Консольное приложение.
Вопрос такой. Как использовать полученное значение аргумента main, в другом классе.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string one = args[0];
    string two = args[1];`
```

Если использовать значение аргумента внутри main, то все впорядке, но как использовать запределами я нагуглить так и не смог.

Comment: Нужно передавать конкретный аргумент (например, `one`) или весь массив (`args`) в соответствующий код: `AnotherClass.Check(one, two);`

Comment: передать аргументами в нужное место

Comment: @Regent Да или на конструктор.

Comment: main точка входа , передавать явно в нужные методы

Comment: как будет правильно передать на конструктор?